# dirección intent en google maps

Tags: java, android

tengo este código, me abre la aplicación de google maps pero jamás me muestra la ubicación, solo me aparece el mapa blanco.
esto es en android:

```
String dir = direccion.getText().toString().trim();
Uri mapUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + dir);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapUri);

mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");       
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

solo necesito escribir la dirección, sin eso de latitud

Comment: Te funciono mi respuesta? veo que no has marcado ninguna de las respuestas de la comunidad como soluciòn, si alguna soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta te sugiero revisar [tour] , saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas abrir el mapa mediante un Intent, **es importante definir la latitud y longitud** de algùn lugar y configurarla en la url, por ejemplo

```
String latitud = "19.1155";
String longitud = "-96.1118";

Uri myUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + latitud +"," + longitud + "(my city)");
```

ahora esta `Uri` definirla en tu Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myUri);
startActivity(intent);
```